# how to set up ubuntu server different fresh magento install?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento2.3

Please tell me I am working Magento 2 on ubuntu now 1 Magento 2.3 is install and running condition so how to download 2 second magento2.3 on localhost this one server?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more in the question?

Comment: What are you using? nginx or apache?

Comment: apache ubuntu 18.04 @ShoaibMunir & already one magento is now running so how to setup new another fresh  magento2.3 this server?@Mohit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new magento directory beside your current magento directory

Like if you have currently using magento in `/var/www/magento2-1`

Then create new directory `/var/www/magento2-2`

**If you are using nginx** then add your new magento entry in config, probably with the name `default` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` file name could be anything else. Code would be like this:

```
server {
     listen 8080;
     server_name www.magento2-1.com;
     set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2-1;
}

server {
     listen 8080;
     server_name www.magento2-2.com;
     set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2-2;
}
```

Copy your first magento configuration to create another, do not rely on my configuration it's just a sample

**If you are using apache** then add your new magento entry in config, probably with the name default.conf in `/etc/apache2/default.conf` file name could be anything else. Code would be like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.magento2-1.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/magento2-1
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/magento2-1>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.magento2-2.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/magento2-2
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/magento2-2>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Copy your first magento configuration to create another, do not rely on my configuration it's just a sample

**In case of nginx restart nginx**

```
service nginx restart
```

**In case of apache restart apache**

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Did it work for you?